# SQL - Returning the Top two Results for Each Match

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have a situation where we record every change to a column of a member record in the `MEMBER` table as a separate row. The changes that are logged only show the column name that was changed, the new value and the date the change was made.

Example: Table Name - CustomerChanges

| customerId | columnName | newValue | dateChanged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | status | Active | 1/12/2021 |
| 1234 | status | Cancelled | 9/30/2020 |
| 1234 | status | Frozen | 7/1/2020 |
| 1234 | status | Active | 1/1/2020 |
| 5678 | status | Active | 1/11/2021 |
| 5678 | status | Frozen | 11/1/2020 |
| 5678 | status | Active | 2/1/2020 |
| 9101 | status | Active | 1/10/2021 |
| 9101 | type | Full Time | 1/10/2021 |
| 9101 | status | Frozen | 10/15/2020 |
| 9101 | status | Active | 1/1/2020 |

I need to do 3 things here:

1. Pull all of the changes for `status` only
2. Grab all of the Customers that went from `Frozen` to `Active`. I believe the way to go about it is to pull the top two records for each `customerId` and  then see who went from `Frozen` to `Active`.
3. Who did it in the specified time frame...in this example it would be `January`.

Considerations:

1. As stated earlier, the table has changes for all columns just not the `status` column.
2. The Customer can have many entries of `status` changes.

I am working in SSRS and have been struggling with this. I tried to query the table for changes to the column `columnName`, group it by `CustomerId`, grab the top two rows and then see which ones went from `Frozen` to `Active`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit messy, there is probably a better way of doing it but this should work.

You will have to adjust the inner-most query to filter on your date range, I didn't include that bit.

I recreated your dataset and then produced the output as follows

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (customerId int, columnName varchar(20), newValue varchar(20), dateChanged date)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1234, 'status', 'Active'   , '2021-01-12' ),
(1234, 'status', 'Cancelled', '2020-09-30' ),
(1234, 'status', 'Frozen'   , '2020-07-01' ),
(1234, 'status', 'Active'   , '2020-01-01' ),
(5678, 'status', 'Active'   , '2021-01-11' ),
(5678, 'status', 'Frozen'   , '2020-11-01' ),
(5678, 'status', 'Active'   , '2020-02-01' ),
(9101, 'status', 'Active'   , '2021-01-10' ),
(9101, 'type', 'Full Time'  , '2021-01-10' ),
(9101, 'status', 'Frozen'   , '2020-10-15' ),
(9101, 'status', 'Active'   , '2020-01-01' )

--SELECT * FROM @t

SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        s.* 
        , LAG(newValue, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY customerId ORDER BY dateChanged) AS PreviousStatus 
        FROM 
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY dateChanged DESC) as RowN
            FROM @t 
            WHERE columnName = 'Status' -- Add date filtering here
        ) s
        WHERE s.RowN < =2
    ) x 
    WHERE newValue = 'Active' AND PreviousStatus = 'Frozen'
```

This gives the following output

[image]